# Overlay frame on ionic 2 camera

Tags: cordova, camera, ionic2

I'm trying to use `Camera` plugin in my ionic app. I want to have some overlay frames on preview for camera but haven't find anything similar to it in description [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera). Also I tried to use `CameraPreview` plugin but it's still in beta besides pictures not being of a good quality. Could anyone suggest how to have an overlay frame on `Camera` preview, please?

Comment: Ok, I've just used [this](https://github.com/erperejildo/cordova-plugin-preview-camera) repo in the end. Seems like it fixes autofocus issue of `CameraPreview` plugin.